# Trying to move munin master from one debian server to another

Tags: munin

I am trying to move munin master node from one debian server to another and preserve the history graphs, how could I proceed (maybe someone can write the instruction on munin wiki website).

Regards, 
Jan

Answer (score 2):

To move the master node from on server to another you need to copy the `/var/lib/munin` directory tree to the new server. You may want to use `rsync` to do this.

Try the copy and run both servers in parallel for a bit.  If you don't want to loose history, you may want to copy files directory by directory or server by server in between munin data fetches.  Use scp or some other unconditional copy for those copies. Fetches at five minute intervals on the fives.

If the copy runs fast enough, or you don't mind missing a sample you can shutdown the new server while you run the final copy.

Once you are happy with the new server, shutdown munin on the old server.